# Reference type in an array

Tags: go

Look at the following code snippet

```
// Prepare some data to insert into the template.
type Recipient struct {
    Name, Gift string
    Attended   bool
}
var recipients = []Recipient{
    {"Aunt Mildred", "bone china tea set", true},
    {"Uncle John", "moleskin pants", false},
    {"Cousin Rodney", "", false},
}
```

I create a struct with some properties. After create a slice with Recipient type. Does slice recipients keeps value or reference type inside?

It seems to be value type.

Comment: Is your question "can I put another type than `Recipient` in the `recipients` slice" ?

Comment: i see now, it is not an array, it is a slice. My question, can I put a pointer into a slice?

Comment: @zero_coding sure, you can put anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slice is in fact a (kind of) pointer to a portion of an array (see [slice usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)), so as for arrays, items are values of the specified type.

Answer (score 2):

It keeps whatever you declared your slice to be. In your case, you declared as `[]Recipient`, so it will keep the data as value.

If you declare a slice as `[]*Recipient`, then it will hold references (`*Recipient`), not `Recipient` values.